# Must then A ∩ B also have a maximum?

Tags: maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\sup(A) = \max\{A\}$ and $\sup(B) = \max\{B\}$ hold,

that is, that the suprema are contained in the respective amount and thus maxima.

**Must then $A \cap B$ also have a maximum?**

If so, prove it. If not, give a counterexample.

I literally have no clue what to do. Please help, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The idea is that $\max A$ and $\max B$ are hardly related to $\sup(A\cap B)$.

Comment: I see from your profile that you have not accepted any answer to your questions until now. Please, consider doing so (see [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers)), if you find useful answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming further that $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$ otherwise this could already be a good case for a counterexample.

Take $A= (0,1)\cup \{2\}$ and $B=(0,1)\cup\{3\}$ then $A\cap B = (0,1)$ has no maximum.

Comment: Note that we could have also taken $B=[0,1]$.